# Ubuntu emergency mode shows up everytime

Tags: ubuntu

I have windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04 dualboot on my laptop. Suddenly linux stopped booting. I'm greeted by the emergency mode and nothing works to get through. The system is not able to boot and work even in recovery mode. Is there any way to not to lose my files saved on the ubuntu partitions and bring it back to normal.

After running some line of code suggested some where to detect corrupted files, some lines marked in red showed up saying that fcsk died with status code 4. The reason seems to be some corrupted files on my laptop. Some errors are:
fsck failed with error code 4,.
Failed to start File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/36568..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09fgJ.jpg)

Comment: The red line is (almost certainly) not relevant. `kvm: disabled by bios` warning was probably there already, you just didn't look for it normally.  KVM is for virtual machines, it is not required at all as part of the Ubuntu boot process.

Comment: Normally I think you should get a specific error message from fsck, or fsck.ext4 specifically.  If you try the command `fsck -A`, I think it should either give you a message, OR start asking you horrible technical yes/no questions where "yes" might potentially damage remaining data.  On the first question, I think you can cancel with ctrl+C (or hold down the power button :-) instead of answering.  This is "not supposed" to happen, unless something went wrong with hardware, or something deliberately overwrote bits of the raw filesystem, etc.

Comment: You question only says "make ubuntu function normally".  The strict answer to that, is to check the hardware, and then re-install ubuntu, overwriting the old install and all of your files on ubuntu.  If you want to get as many of your old files as possible, you ideally want to clone the ubuntu partitions before you attempt any recovery.  Another method is to first recover as much file content as possible (but not the filenames or directory structure!), using `photorec`.

Answer (score 0):

from what you said it sounds like you have two issues.
the first is your computer not booting 
the second is a potential loss of data on your hard drive.

if it was my problem, i would remove the hard drive, install a different blank hard drive. install linux on that , once that is working ,

the second step is to recover the data from the old hard drive,

stress test the old hard drive using badblocks.

if it passes, reformat it, use it to backup the other hard drive.

so now you have a backup of your data,

then you could reinstall windows if you want.